# LESS CSS - Interpolation - can it be made easier?

Tags: css, less

I have LESS variables set up to manage colour selections. Here's part of it:

/* The themes

```
@lightTheme1:@grey300;
@lightTheme2:@grey100;
@lightTheme3:@grey50;
@lightTheme4:#fff;

@darkTheme1:#000;
@darkTheme2:@grey900;
@darkTheme3:#303030;
@darkTheme4:@grey800;
```

/* Set theme name

```
@theme:'lightTheme';
```

/* The chosen theme

```
@theme1:'@{theme}1';
@theme2:'@{theme}2';
@theme3:'@{theme}3';
@theme4:'@{theme}4';
```

/* Using the theme

```
@background:@@theme3;
background-color:@@theme3;
```

The issue I've got is that in order to use @theme1, theme2 etc I need to prefix with '@@'. This is easy to forget because the normal variable syntax is a single '@' - is there anything I can do higher up in the hierarchy so that when I need to use the variables in code I can do so with a single '@'?

Comment: Just don't emulate arrays via variable name concatenation (and kill all the tutorials and examples that suggest to do so). Less have [native arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bless%5D+array).

Answer (score 1):

If you will only be using 1 theme at a time you could store the theme variables in seperate files:

**lightTheme.less**

```
@theme1:@grey300;
@theme2:@grey100;
@theme3:@grey50;
@theme4:#fff;
```

**darkTheme.less**

```
@theme1:#000;
@theme2:@grey900;
@theme3:#303030;
@theme4:@grey800;
```

Then rather than setting the theme via a string property, you can `@import` a theme:

```
@import "lightTheme.less"
```

Then your use of the theme is a single `@`:

```
background-color:@theme3;
```

Comment: Not a bad idea curt, but I'll have to have a think about whether its workable in our scenario.

Comment: @JohnOhara Out of interest why wouldn't this possibly work in your scenario?

Comment: Because, the example extends to colour swatches as well as themes. A colour swatch, (10 shades), can either be used as primary colour or an accent colour. If I was to import blue.less and green.less, there would be confusion as to which colour applied to primary or accent.